# What is faster in those two JavaScript codes?

Tags: javascript, performance

I know that PHP performance is affected by things like these so my question is what is faster.

This one

```
Math.random()*99999
```

or this one

```
new Date().getTime()
```

I intend to use the result to append to a URL for cache-busting purposes.

Comment: There is no practical difference unless you're doing this hundreds or thousands of times on the same page.

Comment: The practical difference is that the two *do entirely different things*.  To worry about whether the current time or some random number is faster, rather than which one is more correct, is a textbook example of premature optimization.  It's the #2 thing that bugs me about PHP programmers in general.  :P

Answer (score 3):

A test case at http://jsperf.com/datevsrand shows that `Math.random()` is significantly faster, but even then on my computer you can generate *6,5 million* timestamps per second.

So, again, there's no practical difference. If there's a performance bottleneck, this won't be it.

Also note that in contrast to a server-side language like PHP it doesn't make any difference to the web site's performance even if you had millions of users because the calculation is done on the client's computer.

Comment: +1 for "if there's a performance bottleneck, this won't be it".  Especially in the example; the time it'll take to connect to the server, retrieve the data, parse it, and replace the current contents of the element will dwarf the sub-microsecond difference.  Concentrate on what's the right thing to do, and stop trying to micro-optimize.